# Equivalences for mCi doses and cGy?

Tags: radioactivity, unit-conversion, medical-physics

I was searching a lot and could only find dosages for curing cancer and allowed emission, but no Iridium 192 dose that could be given internally through brachy sources been found, lets say a 700 cGy dose needed by the patient while the source has the capacity of 10Ci. So what can ascertained as to the consumption of 1 source 10Ci into number patients requiring 700 cGy.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question could be stated more clearly. Are you asking for an equation describing how much of a source with activity 10 Ci should be consumed in a patient to deliver an absorbed dose of 700 cGy? Or are you asking for a reference to read more about it? It might also be helpful to more clearly state the circumstances of delivery.

Comment: I am asking an equation describing how much of a source with activity 10 Ci should be consumed in number of patients, each to deliver an absorbed dose of 700 cGy? And how long that source would decay if I needs to see a useful life of the source.

Comment: I doubt you can calculate that without some measurements or MC simulations. At least, you could clearly explain the treatment procedure, so some can help.